# handsontable formula returning #NEED_UPDATE

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a handsontable, for example:

```
+---+------+-------+-------+
|   |  A   |  B    |  C    | 
+---+------+-------+-------+
| 1 |  10  | 20    |  30   |
+---+------+-------+-------+
| 2 |  5   |=0.5+A3|=0.5+B3|
+---+------+-------+-------+
| 3 |=A1+A2|=B1+B2 |=C1+C2 |
+---+------+-------+-------+
```

when the table is loaded, `B2` and `C2` has value of `#NEED_UPDATE` instead of calculation result of its formula. how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I solved this. add afterRender callback:

```
afterRender: function(){
    this.setDataAtCell(ROW, COL, FORMULA);
}
```

this will automatically update all cell to the right.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by this?  I am having the same issue and unable to figure it out.

Comment: Whatever this solution might mean, I do not believe it will handle many other cases.  The correct resolution to this is (modestly, my post) at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35865132/489865, which handles recursive formula resolution correctly.