# Handsontable RuleJS missing recursive resolution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

I use RuleJS plugin for Handsontable ([see it on GitHub](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable-ruleJS)) which works great for basic formulas but seems to lack recursive resolution.

I've made a code snippet containing two detailed examples, please check it out :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var container1 = $('#example1');
  var container2 = $('#example2');
  
  container1.handsontable({
    data: [[1, '=A2'], ['=B2', '=5 * 2']],
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    formulas: true,
    minSpareRows: 1
  });
  
  container2.handsontable({
    data: [[1, '=A2', 3], ['=C1 * B2', '=5 + 1', 3]], 
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    formulas: true,
    minSpareRows: 1
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/handsontable/handsontable.full.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/handsontable/handsontable.full.css">
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/lib/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/lib/underscore.string/underscore.string.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/lib/numeral/numeral.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/lib/numericjs/numeric.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/lib/js-md5/md5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/lib/jstat/jstat.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/lib/formulajs/formula.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/js/parser.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/js/ruleJS.js"></script>
    <script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/handsontable/handsontable.formula.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/css/samples.css">

    <style type="text/css">
        body {background: white; margin: 20px;}
        h2 {margin: 20px 0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Bugs in handsontable-ruleJS</h2>

  <p>Both cases seem to come from the same problem, but they both worth seeing.</p>
  <p>Here B1 displays the value of B2 <b>before</b> its interpretation where it should display "<b>10</b>". Just like it misses some recursive processing. Focusing the cell will show its real value "<b>=A2</b>" which will next be interpreted correctly.</p>
  <div id="example1" class="handsontable"></div>

  <p>This one is interesting, because when the cell "<b>A2</b>" tries to calculate "<b>C1 * B2</b>" it does "<b>3 * =5 + 1"</b> instead of "<b>3 * 6</b>", which obviously fails.</p>
  <div id="example2" class="handsontable"></div>
  <p>The only way to correct it is to edit "<b>C1</b>" (even without changing its value).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you prefer JSFiddle, [here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/71o23gp0/4/).

Best regards.

**Edit**: You may not see the first bug when using the embed snippet and going to fullscreen because it seems to trigger a refresh of the table. Use the JSFiddle for better results.

**Edit 2 (SOLVED)**: Ok I think I've patched it, [you can find the result here](http://jsfiddle.net/71o23gp0/8/). I'll post a complete answer when Stackoverflow allows me to do it. Any feedback is still welcome, I'm sure there is a better way to do it but at least it seems to work now.

Comment: Could you indeed please post your complete answer now, and explain whatever you had to do to "patch" the Hot code?

Comment: Yep, sorry I've forgotten.. I've switched to another project soon after the creation of this thread. I'll come back to this in a few weeks and I'll need to rewrite the plugin to fit my needs (like adding conditional formatting, custom variables in formulas, ...). I would be more than happy to share it if  it can help some people.

Answer (score 1):

The working code can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/71o23gp0/8/.

The important part was to replace :

```
var custom = {
      cellValue: instance.getDataAtCell
};
```

By

```
var custom = {
        cellValue: function(row, col){
          var value = instance.getDataAtCell(row, col);
          if (value && value[0] === '=') {
              var formula = value.substr(1).toUpperCase();
              var cellId = instance.plugin.utils.translateCellCoords({
                  row: row,
                  col: col
              });
              var item = instance.plugin.matrix.getItem(cellId);

              if (!item) {
                  item = instance.plugin.matrix.addItem({
                      id: cellId,
                      formula: formula
                  });
              } else {
                  item = instance.plugin.matrix.updateItem({
                      id: cellId,
                      formula: formula
                  });
              }
              var formulaResult = instance.plugin.parse(formula, {
                  row: row,
                  col: col,
                  id: cellId
              });
              value = formulaResult.result || '#ERROR';
              formulasResults[cellId] = value;
              instance.plugin.matrix.updateItem(item, {
                  formula: formula,
                  value: formulaResult.result,
                  error: formulaResult.error
              });
          }
          return value;
      }
    };
```

Instead of simply returning the value of the cell, it checks if it's a formula and resolve it if so. Because this method is called by RuleJS when resolving a formula, this make the resolution recursive. The result is then cached for better performance.

There are other minor modifications in the source code, but I've added comments in the fiddle before and after every modification.

Comment: I will be working on this in a while, and will mark your answer as "useful" when I have had a chance to use it.  In the meantime, have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32690231/489865, which seems to be similar problem and proposes a very different, one-line solution?

Comment: That's the first time I see this solution. I don't really understand how it works anyway. It's only one line because it misses a lot of things. I don't understand where his "ROW, COL, FORMULA" come from. If you have a working fiddle using this "one line" solution I would surely be happy to use it. And even if it works, it misses caching which can be very slow if many cells reference a same cell with a formula.

Comment: Thanks, I will examine just your solution then!  Can I be cheeky and ask you if you would look at my new Hot post question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603349/how-to-correctly-install-handsontable-with-rulejs, and see if you can answer?  Thanks!

Comment: I have now tried this solution. I do not pretend to understand the implications, but I confirm that it solves your 2 example cases, **plus** the similar problem in stackoverflow.com/a/32690231/489865!

Comment: There is one new small glitch, though: if you use the default CSS style to show calculated cells in yellow in your examples (which is not there I think in the jsfiddle), you will find that **without** your change all calculated cells are correctly show yellow, but **with** your change only certain ones are, and others are not (e.g. in both your examples **only** cell B1 is yellow. Fix?? :)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35528447/489865 in this question, I have patched a little further.  The working code can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/ufL1vts5/.

The essential change is to store in `formulasResults[]` not just the "result" but rather the whole object returned by `instance.plugin.parse()`, so that cell highlighting for formulas is picked up, as per:

```
// parse formula
var newValue = instance.plugin.parse(formula, {row: row, col: col, id: cellId});
// cache result
formulasResults[cellId] = newValue;
```

My modifications include:

1. Store whole `instance.plugin.parse()` object in `formulasResults[]`,
   so that the `formula`/`formula-error` CSS style gets applied.  [Note
   that this is not perfect: it picks up "calculated" formula style
   correctly, but sometimes what should be `formula-error` style only
   get `formula` style --- but sufficient for my needs.]
2. Added `formula` & `formula-error` CSS styles (from supplied
   `handsontable.formula.css`) into JSFiddle example, so that cell
   highlighting can be seen.
3. Added 2 extra examples: one from
   [handsontable formula returning #NEED_UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689923/handsontable-formula-returning-need-update),
   to show that works too, and one from the example supplied with
   **handsontable-ruleJS** at https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable-ruleJS/blob/master/index.html.
4. Removed the newly added `beforeRender` hook via
   `instance.removeHook('beforeRender', beforeRender);` in `this.init = function ()`.
5. Changed some code layout in `handsontable.formula.js`, so that it
   minimises the differences from that supplied with
   **handsontable-ruleJS**.