# How to correctly install Handsontable with RuleJS

Tags: installation, handsontable

I need to install Handsontable *with* RuleJS support (for formulas) locally (i.e. not just access its files from github), under Windows. I will later need to distribute with my application. I *really* do not want to have to install & configure `bower`, `git` etc.

Initially, starting from https://github.com/handsontable, I tried downloading the `zip` from https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable. Then I had to fetch various extra bits from elsewhere on `github`, attempting to make the demo at http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/ work. This includes its stuff via:

```
<!-- handsontable v1 -->
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/handsontable/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link data-jsfiddle="common" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="lib/handsontable/handsontable.full.css">

<!-- ruleJS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="lib/handsontable/handsontable.formula.css">

<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/RuleJS/lib/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/RuleJS/lib/underscore.string/underscore.string.js"></script>
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/RuleJS/lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/RuleJS/lib/numeral/numeral.js"></script>
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/RuleJS/lib/numericjs/numeric.js"></script>
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/RuleJS/lib/js-md5/md5.js"></script>
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/RuleJS/lib/jstat/jstat.js"></script>
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/RuleJS/lib/formulajs/formula.js"></script>

<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/RuleJS/js/parser.js"></script>
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/RuleJS/js/ruleJS.js"></script>

<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="lib/handsontable/handsontable.formula.js"></script>
```

This is all messy, and (I think) I could not even find the `numericjs/numeric.js` in any download package.

I then noticed https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable-ruleJS. This seemed much simpler: it has the handsontable stuff it wants in its own `bower_components` sub-directory, and its `index.html` example, with files included via:

```
<!-- handsontable --> 
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script> 
<link data-jsfiddle="common" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css"> 

<!-- ruleJS --> 
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="bower_components/ruleJS/dist/full/ruleJS.all.full.js"></script> 
<script data-jsfiddle="common" src="src/handsontable.formula.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="src/handsontable.formula.css">
```

Additionally, its `README.md` states `Important: Few things have been modified in external libraries, so please use all library files only from this repo.`, which makes it sound like this is the safest way to go (and full, latest handsontable release might not even behave correctly).

However, I have just realised that `handsontable-RuleJS` has its included Handsontable stuff at version 0.14.1, while the latest release of that is 0.23, and there are functions I need from later versions.

So, is there a simple way to download what I need? Should I be using the simple `handsontable-RuleJS` link, with its included `bower_components`, or are they *only* there for the `index.html` demo, or overwrite them with newer versions, or what...? Or, do I *really* need to get `bower` & `git`, make them work right under Windows, and then magically everything will be sorted out in a way too difficult to just download directly?

Answer (score 2):

All I did was use https://github.com/handsontable/ruleJS as it was really simple. I took the files I needed for my project and left the rest of it alone. I would just use this and see what functionalities you need from later versions. Then you can go back and include those.
I don't think there is any magical download that will just give you everything you need. You will probably need to play around a little but I don't believe you will need bower and git.

Comment: Do you mean, you started from https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable and merged in whatever you needed from  https://github.com/handsontable/ruleJS?